# How to turn on data compare in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, compare

I am looking to compare two databases using the Data Compare tool in Visual Studio. I've found a number of articles on how to do that, but I cannot get to the Data menu they are referring to in all those articles.

I want to know if there is a way to turn the data compare feature on in VS, so that I can actually see the Data menu and then proceed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that the way to do data compare in Visual Studio 2013 is by using:
**Tools->SQL Server->New Data Comparison/New Schema Comparison**.